# How to make Pythons "keyring" package forget about a password?

Tags: python, authentication, package

I am using [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/) for storing my passwords when uploading packages with [flit](https://pypi.org/project/flit/).

I mistyped one password and now the upload fails and I just can't find a way to reset the wrong password. Even an uninstall didn't help.

Anybody? I already checked the docs but couldn't find anything...

Do I have to go for a programmatic solution? If so, how would this look like?

Thx!